# How to fix unicode data error in SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

I have a postgresql data have some unicode tables.
I have already setup successful for replication but can not send origin unicode data to SQL server.
I have already tried:
mssql.use.ntypes.for.sync=true
 but still have error.
Could someone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Are the column types on the SQL server declared as Unicode https://docs.microfocus.com/SM/9.60/Codeless/Content/database/concepts/MS_SQL_server_unicode_support.htm ?

Comment: Yes, It's nvachar()

Answer (score 0):

Well after make some following changes, it works

Change the connection in property file to:

```
 sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true
 mssql.use.ntypes.for.sync=true
```

But i can see that it will make a big [pressure](https://www.pressurewashersrating.com/) on your server performance.